# Problema ao substituir strings

Tags: c++, string, replace

Oi, eu estou começando a criar um interpretador de equações, eu quero substituir os operadores por palavras, mas as coisas não estão indo bem...

`main.cpp`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

//disables any deprecation warning
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

//usings
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;


string repops(string expr) {
    string iexpr = expr;
    for (int i = 0; i < iexpr.length(); i++) {

        char& c = iexpr[i];

        if (c == '+') {
            iexpr.replace(i, i, " add ");
        }
        if (c == '-') {
            iexpr.replace(i, i, " subtract ");
        }
        if (c == '*') {
            iexpr.replace(i, i, " multiply ");
        }
        if (c == '/') {
            iexpr.replace(i, i, " divide ");
        }
    }
    return iexpr;
}

int main() {
    cout << repops("1+2-1");
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Eu tenho uma saída como essa:

```
1 add 2 subtract
```

Mas eu queria uma como essa:

```
1 add 2 subtract 1
```

Comment: Você está no stackoverflow em português

Comment: Your English is bad? No worry, because we speak Portuguese here! Don't post questions in English, please!

Answer (score 0):

Trata-se de um erro bobo. O segundo parâmetro do `replace` é a quantidade de caracteres que você quer substituir, que em todos os casos deveria ser `1` ao invés de `i`. Fazendo-se essa pequena correção nas 4 operações, o seu código funciona como esperado. [**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/nPAxdq)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode implementar uma função capaz de susbtituir **todas** as ocorrências dentro de uma string, veja só:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void substituir( string& str, const string& de, const string& para )
{
    size_t pos = 0;

    if( de.empty() )
        return;

    while( (pos = str.find(de, pos)) != string::npos )
    {
        str.replace( pos, de.length(), para );
        pos += para.length();
    }
}
```

Testando:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void substituir( string& str, const string& de, const string& para )
{
    size_t pos = 0;

    if( de.empty() )
        return;

    while( (pos = str.find(de, pos)) != string::npos )
    {
        str.replace( pos, de.length(), para );
        pos += para.length();
    }
}

string repops( string expr )
{
    string iexpr = expr;

    substituir( iexpr, "+", " add " );
    substituir( iexpr, "-", " subtract " );
    substituir( iexpr, "*", " multiply " );
    substituir( iexpr, "/", " divide " );

    return iexpr;
}

int main( void )
{
    cout << repops( "1+2-1" ) << endl;
    cout << repops( "5*2/1" ) << endl;
    cout << repops( "7+2-1*4/8" ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
1 add 2 subtract 1
5 multiply 2 divide 1
7 add 2 subtract 1 multiply 4 divide 8
```